# 'FragmentManager is already executing transactions' when switching between Dark Theme and Light theme on API 29+

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

Whenever I use the Notification Shade to switch between the device dark and light themes, (my app when running) always seems to crash for some reason. My app's minimum API is 29 (Android 10). How can I prevent this from happening again?

> FragmentManager is already executing transactions

**Activity class**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        if (savedInstanceState == null) supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.detail_container, MainFragment())
            .commitNow()
    }
}
```

**Main fragment class**

```
package com.example.vp2

import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.TextUtils
import android.view.*
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.Spinner
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import androidx.core.app.NavUtils
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle
import androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
import java.util.*

class MainFragment : androidx.fragment.app.Fragment() {
    private lateinit var mySpinnerItems: Array<String>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        return v
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val mSpinner = requireView().findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.mSpinner)
        val mViewPager2 = requireView().findViewById<ViewPager2>(R.id.mViewPager2)

        // Spinner items array
        mySpinnerItems = arrayOf(
            "Item 1",
            "Item 2",
            "Item 3",
        )

        val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(requireView().context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mySpinnerItems)
        arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item)
   
        mSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
                when {
                    mySpinnerItems[position] == "Item 1" -> {
                        mViewPager2.setCurrentItem(0, false)
                    }

                    mySpinnerItems[position] == "Item 2" -> {
                        mViewPager2.setCurrentItem(1, false)
                    }

                    else -> {
                        mViewPager2.setCurrentItem(2, false)
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {
                mViewPager2.setCurrentItem(0, false)
            }
        }
        mSpinner.adapter = arrayAdapter

        mViewPager2.adapter = MySpinnerFragmentAdapter(fragmentManager, lifecycle)
        mViewPager2.orientation = ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL

        mViewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                when (position) {
                    0 -> {
                        mSpinner.setSelection(0)
                    }
                    1 -> {
                        mSpinner.setSelection(1)
                    }
                    else -> {
                        mSpinner.setSelection(2)
                    }
                }
                super.onPageSelected(position)
            }
        })

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    }

    private class MySpinnerFragmentAdapter(fm: FragmentManager?, lifecycle: Lifecycle) : FragmentStateAdapter(fm!!, lifecycle) {
        private val intItems = 3

        override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
            return when (position) {
                0 -> Fragment1()
                1 -> Fragment2()
                else -> Fragment3()
            }
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return intItems
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
        menu.clear()
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return if (item.itemId == android.R.id.home) {
            val intent = activity?.let { NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(it) }
            when {
                intent != null -> {
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION)
                    NavUtils.navigateUpTo(requireActivity(), intent)
                }
            }
            true
        } else super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

**Main activity layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/detail_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

**Main fragment layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/detail_container">

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/mViewPager2"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <!-- divider (start)-->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/textColorSecondary" />
    <!-- divider (end)-->

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/mSpinner"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

[image]

Comment: If your `MySpinnerFragmentAdapter` is always used within a `Fragment`, you should use the `FragmentStateAdapter(Fragment)` constructor, which always uses the right `FragmentManager` and `Lifecycle`.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Are you suggesting `private class MySpinnerFragmentAdapter(fa: FragmentActivity) : FragmentStateAdapter(fa)` instead of `private class MySpinnerFragmentAdapter(fm: FragmentManager?, lifecycle: Lifecycle) : FragmentStateAdapter(fm!!, lifecycle)`?

Comment: No, `private class MySpinnerFragmentAdapter(fragment: Fragment) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragment)`

Comment: Then what should be in the parentheses of `mViewPager2.adapter = MySpinnerFragmentAdapter()`?

Comment: You'd pass your fragment in: `MySpinnerFragmentAdapter(this)`